# Firebug not showing ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebug

I have all tabs enabled... like a week ago it just stopped showing ajax requests in the console.... I'm not sure what to do about it.  Any ideas on what I can do to fix it?

**Update**

When I use console.log(el); it says console is undefined as well.

Comment: This happened to me a little while ago, I updated Firebug and I have to close/reopen Firefox to get the Console to work again. I'd also like to know a good solution.

Comment: For me, firebug just sometimes stops working properly.  Once or twice a week during dev I end up having to restart FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uninstalled Firebug and have reinstalled it.  I am now on 1.5.3 and it works just fine.

Glad to have it resolved ^_^

Answer (score 2):

In my case with the combinations

> Firefox **14.0.1** + Firebug **1.10.0**
>
> Firefox **10.0.4** + Firebug **1.9.2**

the solution was turning the Net/Network panel ***on*** in order to see ajax-requests/-responses in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the version of Firebug is correct for your version of Firefox.

Comment: I have both the latest Firebug and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing the menu icon for the Console tab to see if you have it showing XMLHttpRequests?

Answer (score 0):

yes same for me - I's still the same after FB downgrade to 1.5.0 - I think it started happening after one the FF updates...

Answer (score 0):

I've found that turning off the network tab resolves the problem. It seems like a recent update makes it difficult to display the requests both in the console and in the network tabs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 4.0 beta does not support Ajax request logging. For Firebug 1.6 on Firefox 3.6 there are no bug reports about missing Ajax requests.